# How to achieve line above right-aligned caption in floating figure in ConTeXt?

Tags: floats, captions, context, rules, line

I would like to achieve, what in Adobe InDesign is called a *paragraph rule* over a figure's caption, i.e a line on top of the caption, while keeping the caption itself right-aligned (actually aligned to the inner edge).

Here's an MWE (note that this MWE is similar to what I posted for a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/673913/how-to-position-a-figure-with-a-colored-page-background-on-the-opposite-page-of) and will soon be reworked to incorporate the suggestions I received there):

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout
[
  backspace=11.67mm,        width=131.25mm,
  topspace=21.21mm,         height=254.57mm,
  headerdistance=13pt,      header=13pt,
  footerdistance=13pt,      footer=13pt,
  rightmargindistance=13pt, rightmargin=39.5mm,
]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, location=]

\setuphead[section][
  page=right,
  continue=no,
  style=\ssb\bf,
]


\definefloat[pagefloat][pagefloats][graphic]
\setupfloat[pagefloat][
  default={page,header,footer},
]
\setupcaption[pagefloat][
  width=max,
  location=top,
  topframe=on,
  toffset=\dimexpr 0.25\lineheight \relax,
  headstyle=\ss\bf,
  style=\tfx,
  align=inner,
  spaceinbetween=nowhite,
]

\def\PageFigure#1#2%
  {
  \placepagefloat[]{#2}{
    \offset[
      leftoffset=\dimexpr -\rightmarginwidth - \lineheight \relax,
    ]{
      \externalfigure[#1][
        width=\dimexpr \textwidth + \rightmarginwidth + \lineheight \relax,
        height=\textheight,
        factor=fit,
      ]
    }
  }
}


\starttext

\chapter{Testing Ruled Captions}

\dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth}}

\PageFigure{https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900.png?text=Wide+Test+Image}{First line\\Second line of the caption}

\section{First Section}

\dorecurse{4}{\input{knuth}}

\stoptext
```

This is what it looks like, when I **remove** the line `topframe=on,`: This is how I would like to align the text.

[image]

But here's, what it looks like with the **topframe on**:

[image]

Why does merely adding the top frame change the alignment of the text? Can this be prevented or, better even, adjusted separately?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that I understand what you want, but maybe something like this? Note the `location={top,right}`. In your definition of `PageFigure` you had spurious spaces (try the example with your definition, and you will see how they show). Also, setting the size of the paper to A4 is not necessary, that is the default.

I first forgot. The `topframe=on` makes your code go into a different path (with a frame), and that is responsible for the effect you see.

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout
[
  backspace=11.67mm,        width=131.25mm,
  topspace=21.21mm,         height=254.57mm,
  headerdistance=13pt,      header=13pt,
  footerdistance=13pt,      footer=13pt,
  rightmargindistance=13pt, rightmargin=39.5mm,
]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, location=]

\setuphead[section][
  page=right,
  continue=no,
  style=\ssb\bf,
]


\definefloat[pagefloat][pagefloats][graphic]
\setupfloat[pagefloat][
  default={page,header,footer},
]

\setupcaption[pagefloat][
   location={top,right},
   topframe=on,
   toffset=0.25\lineheight,
   headstyle=\ss\bf,
   style=\tfx,
   align=inner,
   spaceinbetween=nowhite,
]

\starttexdefinition PageFigure #1#2
  \placepagefloat
    {#2}
    {\offset
      [leftoffset=\dimexpr - \rightmarginwidth - \lineheight \relax] 
      {\externalfigure
         [#1]
         [width=\dimexpr \textwidth + \rightmarginwidth + \lineheight \relax,
          height=\textheight,
          factor=fit]}}
\stoptexdefinition

\showframe

\starttext

\chapter{Testing Ruled Captions}

\dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth}}

\PageFigure{https://via.placeholder.com/1600x900.png?text=Wide+Test+Image}{First line\par Second line of the caption}

\section{First Section}

\dorecurse{4}{\input{knuth}}

\stoptext
```

[image: caption over figure]

**Update** Hans has now opened up the possibilities a bit. Note the `loffset` that will take care of the extra piece of the bar.

In addition, I have done a few modifications:

- Added `location=inner` to the float, and also removed the `offset` (I did not understand the `\lineheight` you had there).
- Changed to `\start...\stop` syntax.

If we (you) are lucky, there will be a new release soon where this is included.

```
\useMPlibrary[dum]

\setuplayout
  [backspace=11.67mm,        width=131.25mm,
   topspace=21.21mm,         height=254.57mm,
   headerdistance=13pt,      header=13pt,
   footerdistance=13pt,      footer=13pt,
   rightmargindistance=13pt, rightmargin=39.5mm]

\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,location=]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [page=right,
   continue=no,
   style=\ssb\bf]

\defineframed
  [MyCaptionFramed]
  [align={lohi,flushleft},
   width=fit,
   frame=off,
   strut=no,
   topframe=on,
   loffset=3cm,
   toffset=0.25\lineheight]

\starttexdefinition protected MyCaption #1
  \MyCaptionFramed {
    % we ignore #1 as we want to unpack
    \unvbox\floatcaptionbox
  }
\stoptexdefinition

\definefloat[pagefloat][pagefloats][graphic]

\setupfloat
  [pagefloat]
  [default={page,header,footer},
   location=inner]

\setupcaption
  [pagefloat]
  [location={top,inner},
   align=inner,
   command=\MyCaption,
   spaceinbetween=nowhite]

\starttexdefinition PageFigure #1#2
  \startplacefloat
    [pagefloat]
    [title={#2}]
      \externalfigure
        [#1]
        [width=\dimexpr \textwidth + \rightmargintotal \relax,
         height=\textheight,
         factor=fit]
  \stopplacefloat
\stoptexdefinition

\showframe

\starttext

\startchapter[title={Testing Ruled Captions}]

  \dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth}}

  \PageFigure
    {some dummy}
    {First line\\Second line of the caption}

  \startsection[title={First Section}]

    \dorecurse{4}{\input{knuth}}

  \stopsection

\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: updated version]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. However, unfortunately, this is not exactly what I wanted to achieve. If you look at the first of the two screenshots you can see that the caption's text is right-aligned (`inner`), as long as the `topframe` is turned off (i.e. when the line `topframe=on,` is commented out). But, as soon as I add the topframe, the text becomes left-aligned: see my second screenshot or your example. I'm not sure, how to keep the text right-aligned, while adding a line above the caption...

Comment: The configuration possibilities can indeed be improved here. I will discuss this with Hans in the near future. He sent me a first draft, so locally I currently have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY0T0.png).

Comment: Thanks, that looks more or less exactly like what I would like to achieve. (It would be perfect, if it was also possible to adjust the length of the topframe, but that's a minor point.) So, is this only possible in your local draft version?